# Umbraco SQL query email property as parameter '@' exception

Tags: sql, email, umbraco

I am querying database to find records searching as for e-mail. Although, I get an exception related to '@' character of e-mail. What is the right syntax to pass e-mail as parameter?

Any help is welcome[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCyXx.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @ is the character used to specify query parameters, so that's why your code is breaking. Also by joining the string by hand you are vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Use this syntax instead

```
.Where("Email=@0", dummyEmail)
```

the query builder will replace the @0 with the correct escaped value of dummyEmail